# Migration from old CMS to WordPress 301 redirection rules?

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess, rewrite-rules, migration

I need 301 redirection rule for migrating old CMS to WordPress.

On old CMS I have URL structure like this:

I wish is to move my site to WordPress and to have all old (or most) URLs with 301 redirect to new pages.

Category url on old CMS:

www.my-site-name.com/category-name-some-category-suffix/

www.my-site-name.com/category-name-some-category-suffix/page/2/

www.my-site-name.com/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name-some-category-suffix/

www.my-site-name.com/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name-some-category-suffix/page/2/

Post urls on old CMS.

www.my-site-name.com/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name-some-category-suffix/some-post-name.jpg.html

and one add-on page for every post like:

www.my-site-name.com/full-size/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name-some-category-suffix/some-post-name.jpg-some-words-here.html

---

Category url on WordPress:

I have for example "**category_url**" as category base, also I wish to remove "**-some-category-suffix**" from category, and subcategory (if any).

For category URLs to:

add "**category_url/**" after domain name

remove "**-some-category-suffix**" from category, and any subcategories

to redirect to URL like this:

www.my-site-name.com/category_url/category-name/

www.my-site-name.com/category_url/category-name/page/2/

---

Post urls on WordPress.

My permalink structure is "**category-url**/%category%/%postname%.html". Please note difference between category base "category_url" and post base "category-url".

For post page to:

remove "**-some-category-suffix**" from category, and any subcategories

rename "**.jpg.html**" to "**.html**"

to redirect to URL like this:

www.my-site-name.com/category-url/category-name/subcategory-name/some-post-name.html

---

For post add-on page to:

remove "**-some-category-suffix**" from category, and any subcategories

rename "**full-size**" to "**category-url**"

rename "**.jpg-**" to "**.html-?**"

remove ending "**.html**" (after "-some-words-here")

to redirect to URL like this:

www.my-site-name.com/category-url/category-name/subcategory-name/some-post-name.html-?some-words-here

---

Summary.

Category from:

www.my-site-name.com/category-name**-some-category-suffix**/

to:

www.my-site-name.com/**category_url**/category-name/

Post from:

www.my-site-name.com/category-name**-some-category-suffix**/subcategory-name**-some-category-suffix**/some-post-name**.jpg.html**

to:

www.my-site-name.com/**category-url**/category-name/subcategory-name/some-post-name**.html**

Post add-on page from:

www.my-site-name.com/**full-size**/category-name**-some-category-suffix**/subcategory-name**-some-category-suffix**/some-post-name**.jpg-**some-words-here**.html**

to:

www.my-site-name.com/**category-url**/category-name/subcategory-name/some-post-name**.html-?**some-words-here

Any help would be great, if rewrite rules are not possible for all URL types than please for some of them.

---

I tried this:

```
#For post page URLs
RewriteRule ^(.*)-some-category-suffix(.*).jpg.html(.*)$ /category-url/$1$2.html$3 [L,R=301]

#For post add-on page URLs
RewriteRule ^full-size/(.*)-some-category-suffix(.*).jpg-(.*).html(.*)$ category-url/$1$2.html-?$3$4 [L,R=301]

#Category URLs
RewriteRule ^(.*)-some-category-suffix(.*)$ /category_url/$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

It works, if there is just one category level, it removes just last "-some-category-suffix".

Output examples

For post pages

www.my-site-name.com/category-url/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name/some-post-name.html

or for post add on page

www.my-site-name.com/category-url/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name/some-post-name.html-?some-words-here

or for category

www.my-site-name.com/category_url/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name/

I need little tweak of it to **remove all instance of "-some-category-suffix"** if more than one in URL.

If you can fix that and make other rules that would be nice.

Any advice, help?

Comment: What have you already tried in for rewrite rules in .htaccess? WPSE is not a "give me the codes site." Have you searched for an answer? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer.

Comment: ** RewriteRule ^full-size/(.*)-some-category-suffix(.*).jpg-(.*).html(.*)$ category-url/$1$2.html-?$3$4 [L,R=301] **

 It works, if there is just one category level, it removes just last "-some-category-suffix".
 www.my-site-name.com/category-url/category-name-some-category-suffix/subcategory-name/some-post-name.html-?some-words-here
 
 I need little tweak of it to ** remove all instance of "-some-category-suffix" ** if more than one in URL.
If you can fix thiat and make other rules that would be nice.

Comment: I updated my rewrite roles, but still I need little help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made modification of rules, now it is working fine.

```
#For post page URLs
RewriteRule ^(.*)-some-category-suffix(.*)-some-category-suffix(.*).jpg.html(.*)$ /category-url/$1$2$3.html [L,R=301]

#For post add-on page URLs
RewriteRule ^(.*)full-size/(.*)-some-category-suffix(.*)-some-category-suffix(.*).jpg-(.*)(.*).html$ /category-url/$1$2$3$4.html?-$5$6 [L,R=301]

#Category URLs
RewriteRule ^(.*)-some-category-suffix(.*)-some-category-suffix(.*)$ /category_url/$1$2$3 [L,R=301]
```